# How to watch multiple criteria then plotchar() there?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My Pine script calculates a bunch of everything, twice. The final challenge is to mark the price if multiple criterion is met.

Just for testing purpose, I found a marker code line [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Text_and_shapes.html)

```
plotchar(ta.rising(close, 5), "`plotchar()`", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
```

Well, okay, I don't get what's that `ta.rising()` part and what's that `5` in the `(close, 5)` part but it works well standalone and I see something (some unwanted green triangles on the chart; it's cool). **But** if I insert an `IF RSI <= 30`:

```
if rsi <= 30
plotchar(ta.rising(close, 5), "`plotchar()`", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
```

… then not the `if` line but the `plotchar` line returns with an error message: `Mismatched input 'plotchar' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.` (I repeat, it works without that IF …)

In case I put a tabulator before the `plotchar`:

```
if rsi <= 30
    plotchar(ta.rising(close, 5), "`plotchar()`", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
```

… then the error message is: `Cannot use 'plotchar' in local scope.`

So I'm obviously far from the thread. **What's the right usage of this code part?** And eventually, **how to make it put that triangle below the candle if (in this case) RSI goes under 30?** (It's the built-in RSI source code there, waiting for something to RSI…)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `plot()` functions in local scope.

You can add your condition to the `series` argument of your `plot()` function.

```
plotchar((rsi <= 30) and (ta.rising(close, 5)), "`plotchar()`", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
```

Comment: Wow, it's too simple. :D And what's that "ta.rising(close,5)" part? Likely I don't need it but need something else, some other criteria. How to make it place those triangles below every single candles if the RSI criteria triggers?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out, the right syntax is:

```
plotchar((rsi <= 30) and (ta.rising(close, 5)), "`plotchar()`", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
```

How to make it place those triangles below every single candles the RSI criteria triggers on?

Okay, it was obvious:

```
plotchar(rsi <= 30), "`plotchar()`", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
```

Now after some experimentation, I finally found it out how to combine criterions.